# How to deploy a MEVN stack app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, heroku

I've built a simple notes manager app using Vue for front end and Express + Mongo for backend. The server and client are in two separate folders, each with its own package.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy you Vue app separatly to a static site hosting provider like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)
And you can host you Express app separatly in Heroku
For you data base, you can host it in [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/)
Start by hosting you express app first